# What's SHAP contribution dependency plots from xgboost package in R?

Tags: machine-learning, r, xgboost

```
clf = xgboost(data.matrix(train2), label = train$MACROSOMIA,objective = "binary:logistic", nrounds = 20)
pred = predict(clf, data.matrix(test[, -12]))

xgb.plot.shap(data.matrix(test2), model = clf, plot_loess =TRUE,features= "GESTAC")
```

This is my code, and I get a SHAP feature contribution to prediction dependencies on feature value. I just have a hard time understanding it. I wonder what is it? How do I interpret it?

Here's [a link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/xgboost.pdf)! Could you help me understand what does this plot mean?

```
xgb.plot.shap()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An insightful blog about the SHAP values is [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-feature-attribution-method-to-supposedly-rule-them-all-shapley-values-f3e04534983d).

In short, the graph shows the contribution to the predicted odds ratio for each value of the variable on the x-axis. It accounts for interactions and correlations with other predictor variables in a clever way.

The values are NOT odds ratios themselves, but contributions to the odds ratio for a single variable. The overall odds ratio could be at a very  different level.

Answer (score 1):

[image: This is the output from xgboost package]

On the y axis. That represents the log odd ratios. The formula is log(p/1-p)

P/1-P  P represents probability of success. 1- P represents probability of failure.

When log odd ratio is 0. It means odd is 1. Probability of success is the same as the probability of failure.

When log odd ratio is below 0, it means that the probability of sucess is less than probability of failure.

When log odd ratio is above 0, it means that the probability of sucess is higher than probability of failure.

Comment: Are you really sure about the interpretation of the values on y axis you gave in your answer? Because, up to my knowledge, the Shap coefficient itself should not be the same as the log odds ratio (it should be the contribution to the log odds ratio associated to the presence of the given level of the considered feature). Can you please provide any reference or more detailed explanation? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I think I answered that question when I was taking a machine learning class. I am still trying to find my references. Feel free to edit my answer if you see fit.